# ffmpeg-python multiple outputs at different resolutions

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am using `ffmpeg-python` to convert `.mp4` files to HLS streamable formats. Currently I can get it to work at full resolution using this piece of code

```
video = ffmpeg.input(file_path)
output = ffmpeg.output(
  video,
  filename=f"{base_path}{uuid}.m3u8",
  format="hls",
  start_number=0,
  hls_time=10,
  hls_list_size=0
)

output.run()
```

If the original video is `1920x1080` the resulting `.ts` files will be of the same resolution. What do I have to do to get multiple resolutions? Say `360p` `480p`, `720p`?

And how does `ffmpeg` handle a resolution when the original is smaller? Say I try to convert a `480p` video to a resolution of `720p`?

Comment: [Converting video from 1080p to 720p with smallest quality loss using ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/714804/converting-video-from-1080p-to-720p-with-smallest-quality-loss-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: in [examples](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/tree/master/examples) you can see `.filter('scale', width, -1)` and the same should works `.filter('scale', -1, 720)`